# php - get meta value by using meta key from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select, while-loop, selector

I have a query like
**SELECT *
FROM `membermetas`
WHERE memberId =15**

Table image :

[image]

and my php code is

```
$memberMetaQuery = "select * from membermetas where memberId='$id'";
$getMemberMeta = mysql_query($memberMetaQuery);
$memberMetaRow = mysql_fetch_array($getMemberMeta);
```

when i use "`echo $memberMetaRow['memberMeta']`" without while loop, it turns the last row.

For example:
i would like to use only the row "`eposta`" and its value "`mail@mymail.com`"
is there any selector for this?

I think that, maybe i can use like `$memberMetaRow['memberMeta']['eposta']` but it's not working as you know :)

How can i get this meta value without using mysql query?
is this possible with a php selector?

Comment: how ur table looks like ?

Comment: Hence the inconvenience of [tag:entity-attribute-value].

Comment: Seems like the design is wrong. You can't get it unless you know the value of the `id` column say `653`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are ready to mention eposta manually like

`$memberMetaRow['memberMeta']['eposta']`

THEN its better to append query to

```
$memberMetaQuery = "select * from membermetas where memberId='$id' and memberMeta='eposta'";
```

Infact this can be use useful a function like

```
function call_data($id,$name){
 $memberMetaQuery = "select * from membermetas where memberId='$id' and memberMeta='$name'";
 $getMemberMeta = mysql_query($memberMetaQuery);
 $memberMetaRow = mysql_fetch_array($getMemberMeta);
 return($memberMetaRow);
}
```

THEN you can call

```
$data = call_data(15,'eposta');
```

Comment: i understand that my table design seems like wrong but making a function solves my problem easily.. thanks a lot..