# Get meta value by using meta key from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working with wordpress. I am going to make custom filter. In which I want  memberId using metakey.

My table structure like below table.
[image]

Reference Question: [php - get meta value by using meta key from mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326557/php-get-meta-value-by-using-meta-key-from-mysql)

My Final statement is below:

```
select distinct(memberid) from membermetas 
where memberMeta = 'kilo' 
and memberMetaValue >= 90 
and memberMeta = 'boy' 
and memberMetaValue <= 175
```

When I am trying to write this query I got nothing.

#### How to write query for getting memberId for 2 or 3 condition on memberMeta field?

Comment: Try using brackets to group your condition `select distinct(memberid) from membermetas where (memberMeta = 'kilo' and memberMetaValue >= 90) and (memberMeta = 'boy' and memberMetaValue <= 175)`

Comment: You might miss the database prefix inside the table name.

Comment: @MahaDev I have written prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have write below query and it works perfectly. My query is :

```
 select membermetas.memberid from membermetas
 INNER JOIN membermetas as table1 ON  membermetas.memberid = table1.memberid AND table1.memberMeta = 'kilo' AND table1.memberMetaValue >= '90'  
 WHERE membermetas.memberMeta = 'boy' AND membermetas.memberMetaValue >= '175'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are querying for `memberMeta` equals `kilo` **AND** equals `boy`, this will obviously never be true. You probably seek a or condition:

```
select distinct(memberid) from membermetas 
where 
(memberMeta = 'kilo' and memberMetaValue >= 90)
OR
(memberMeta = 'boy' and memberMetaValue <= 175)
```

If you however want to have the `memberMetaValue` condition apply for both `memberMeta` matches, then it would be:

```
select distinct(memberid) from membermetas 
where (memberMeta = 'kilo' OR memberMeta = 'boy')
AND (memberMetaValue >= 90 AND memberMetaValue <= 175)
```

You can even simplify this more, to:

```
select distinct(memberid) from membermetas 
where (memberMeta = 'kilo' OR memberMeta = 'boy')
AND (memberMetaValue BETWEEN 90 AND 175)
```

Comment: If I have both memberMetaValue of different memberMeta then write this query then do not get anything if I used **and**.

Comment: That was my point, the problem is that you are using **and**. I am sorry but I don't fully understand your english in this sentence though. Could you elaborate or rephrase that? Maybe creating a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for demonstrating your problem would be even better!

Comment: I have two mandatory field **memberMeta** as kilo and boy so i have to use **and** instead of **or**.

Comment: I still don't get what you are getting at. The same field can never contain two precise values at the same time. Only in different rows, and if you want to match those, you have to use the **or**.

Comment: And btw, with your updated question - "How to write query for getting memberId for 2 or 3 condition on memberMeta field?" -> this is exactly what I answered: Use `OR` :)

Comment: The OP wants the member ids that satisfy BOTH sets of criteria.

Comment: @Strawberry How is this supposed to ever be possible? one attribute of one entitiy can never have one value AND a different one? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry, but not very helpful. I try my best to help out here, but I don't see any "2 sets of criteria", maybe the language barrier is too high, or I am too stupid to comprehend. OP: I will try my best to help you further if you bother to help me understand what you actually want. Can't do anything more.

Comment: See my answer, by way of example.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,memberid INT NOT NULL
,memberMeta VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,memberMetaValue VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,UNIQUE(memberid,membermeta)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(654, 15,'ulke','Türkiye'),
(653, 15,'eposta','mail@mymail.com'),
(652, 15,'alternatiftel','0000000000'),
(651, 15,'telno','0000000001'),
(650, 15,'kilo','90'),
(649, 15,'boy','175'),
(648, 15,'adsoyad','TestTest'),
(647, 15,'tckimlik','12345678901'),
(655, 15,'yas','23'),
(656, 15,'gozrengi','Elaa');

SELECT memberid 
  FROM my_table
 WHERE (memberMeta = 'kilo' AND memberMetaValue >= 90)
    OR (memberMeta = 'boy' AND memberMetaValue <= 175)
 GROUP 
    BY memberid 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;

+----------+
| memberid |
+----------+
|       15 |
+----------+
```

Answer (score -2):

ok can you provide a screenshot of your table? I ask this because your question doesn't typically fit in wordpress usual table structure. by that I mean unless you changed it on install wp tables all have the prefix wp_'tableName'. Now there is an option to change that on install most people ignore that.

next I ask that because wordpress structure for user tables is much different than that. user_id, user_name, etc.

Last I ask for that because the reference you provided never said that was a wordpress table.

Also if you are sure the query is correct how about your connection to the DB? are you using PDO,MySQL,MySqlite? there could be multiple reasons not to get results.

Last wordpress has a very secure structure its not simply lets just write a query and connect to the database, if you are doing that in wordpress  you need to hook into the database first then use the built in functions to make the query, create new tables ect. If you are doing it outside of wordpress you can access the database but if your script isn't written well you are exposing your whole site to injection.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer. Answers should be answering the question, comments are for requesting more information on the issue.

Comment: I have used wp_postmeta table which is similer to the given table link

Comment: @ArSeN look in order to efficiently help him more information was needed. you may walk blindly into things and enjoy wasting your time as well as others or maybe you just like debates either way I don't really care. I would have commented this request but it wouldn't let me comment. I am truly amazed that someone who willingly walks blind through helping someone else ever got a rank above 400

Comment: I just pointed out that there are rules as of [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a question here. No offense intended.